# Solr schema field

Tags: solr

I've made a schema for solr and I don't know the name of every field from the document I want to add, so I defined a dynamicField like this:

```
<dynamicField name="*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Right now I'm testing and I don't get an error when importing for undefined fields in the document, but when I try to query for `*:something` (anything other than "*") I don't get any results back.
My question is how can I define a catch all field, is there any right way to do this? Or am I under the wrong impression that a query for `*:something` would normally search in all the documents and all the fields for "something"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search key word `*:something` can not get anything from solr, no matter what kind of field you are using, dinamicField or not.

If I understand your question correctly, you want a dynamicField to store all fields and want to query all fields laterly.

Here is my solution.

First, defining a default_search field for search:

```
<field name="default_search" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

And then copy all fields into the default_search field.

```
<copyField source="*" dest="default_search" />
```

Finally, you can make a query for all fields like this:

```
http://host/core/select/?q=something
```

or

```
http://host/core/select/?q=default_search:something
```

Comment: Thank you, I already had a search field and copied * to it, just that I didn't reindex before I posted the question, and it wasn't working then and I thought I missed something. Now it works fine.
One more question just to get it right, the query works for `*:*` and `search:something`, but not for `*:something` .  I thought * was a replacement for field name, so what is the * for in the first query `*:*`?

Comment: I don't know it clearly. I thought the `*:*` is just design for searching everything. `*:something` is not a valid query. Once you have the search field you can search on it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `*:something` does not query all the fields. It looks for a field names `*`.

I get the below error when attempting to do a query for `*:test`

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">400</int>
        <int name="QTime">9</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="wt">xml</str>
            <str name="q">*:test</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <lst name="error">
        <str name="msg">undefined field *</str>
        <int name="code">400</int>
    </lst>
</response>
```

You would need to define a catchall field using `copyField` in your `schema.xml`.

I would recommend not using a simple wildcard for dynamic fields. Instead something like this:

```
<dynamicField name="*_text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

and then have a catchall field

```
<field name="CatchAll" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

You can have a `copyField` defined as below, to support query such as `q=something`

```
<copyField source="*_text" dest="CatchAll" />
```